# GVIM vimgrep in windows

Tags: windows, vim, vimgrep

I am trying to replicate Notepad++ find in all files in GVim on windows.
I found the following script for vimgrep which seems to find the word under the cursor in directories

```
map <F4> :execute "vimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j /**/*.c " <Bar> cw<CR>
```

I modified it to search always in a the root directory of my project. But it is not working. The project is under "c:\lion"

```
map < F4> :execute "vimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j {c:\lion\}/**/*.c " <Bar> cw<CR>
```

The following error is shown.

```
"{c:" Illegal file name
Cannot open file "{c:"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `{...}`, and just insert the path as-is, like you would on the command-line (a mapping is nothing more than a recorded macro). It's easier to use forward slashes; these work on Windows, too.

```
:map <F4> :execute "vimgrep /" . expand("<cword>") . "/j C:/lion/**/*.c " <Bar> cw<CR>
```

Maybe you've been confused by the `:execute`. There's another way (with `c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`) to insert the current word, which avoids this:

```
:map <F4> :vimgrep /<C-r><C-w>/j C:/lion/**/*.c <Bar> cw<CR>
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.